# When running PCA on my dataframe, my computer bluescreens

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, pca

I'm working on a data science school project for determining motions of certain dogs. I have a dataframe of extracted attributes (79 in total), plus a label that I'm trying to guess using a machine learning algorithm - so this is a regular classification problem. The number of possible labels is 30, all of which encode a motion the dog is currently doing (0 - stand, 1 - walk, 2 - run, etc.) Each row is a 0.2 second timeframe where we've measured a bunch of attributes the dog was doing in that timeframe.

Here is how my dataframe looks like:

> ```
>   label attribute_1 attribute_2  ... attribute_79
> 1     0    0.199574    0.203156  ...     0.046898   
> 2     1    0.201461    0.203837  ...     0.075002   
> 3     3    0.209044    0.214268  ...     0.143278
> ...   ...       ...         ...  ...          ...
> ```

PCA or Principal Component Analysis is a common algorithm for reducing the amount of attributes (columns) in a dataframe. It creates linear combinations of current attributes, so that my data still keeps a lot of variance, and still "explains" a lot about the label to guess; while having less overall information. It's a slow algorithm (it uses eigenvectors of large matrices), but it only has to be done once, then I can run algorithms on the smaller dataframe. (A lot of algorithms favor smaller dataframes, like SVM or kNN.)

I've already ran other built-in sklearn methods, and I've never ran into such a drastic issue. I might have gotten an error that my current data doesn't work for that specific algorithm, but never a bluescreen.

Here is my current code (it's very basic, just dataframe transformations, then PCA itself):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data = pd.read_csv("../Data/all_windowed_200.csv", sep=',').dropna()
data.shape # outputs (178884, 81)
data.head() # shows the dataframe above
data = data.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1) # this drops the index that gets included automatically in the first column

num_data = data.values
labels = num_data[:, 0]
X = num_data[:, 1:]
pca = PCA().fit(X) # running this line causes the bluescreen
```

This is the PC I'm using:

- Intel 5160 Dual Core @ 3.00 GHz + 3.00 GHz
- 8.00 GB RAM
- AMD Radeon HD 5450 Graphics card
- 64-bit Windows 7

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run my Python code. (Python version 3.6.5, MSC v.1900)

Any help for figuring out why my PC could be bluescreening when running PCA on a my dataframe would be very much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you should specify the number of components you want, for example 10? pca = PCA(n_components=10).fit(X)

Comment: No, later you can specify the amount. You can also plot a graph where x coordinates are the resulting components after PCA, y is the variance it explains. I would like it to explain about 95% variance, then I'll choose the number of components according to that limit.

Comment: My guess: it was your RAM. Run MemTest86 to see if there is any problem

Comment: I bet that when you start with setting a limited number of components, it will be less memory intensive. Then if the amount of components is too small, you can still increase the amount of components.

Comment: I tried it with quarter of the attributes (about 20 instead of 79), and it worked, but that doesn't solve the issue. Splitting the columns in 4, doing PCA on all of them, then pasting them together isn't the same as doing PCA on the entire dataframe.
I have constantly checked the Windows Task Manager while running that line of code, and Python never used more than 1GB of RAM. My guess is that there is not enough RAM allocated to Jupyter Notebook. So how do I go about doing that?